# radio modification with php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this script =>

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['username'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['email'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['rights'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['last_seen'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['since'] . "</span></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='radio_place'><input type='radio' name='choose' onclick='showModification()' id='get_" . $data['username'] . "' value='" . $data['rights'] . "'></span></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

And like you see guys, I have radio buttons and after `onclick` them I have made to show up next form =>

and with `showModification()` function (javascript) I appear next html form for data modification

and here is the face of this form =>

```
<div id="mod_div">
   <select name="option" id="option">
       <option value="sel">*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*</option>
       <option value="null">0</option>
       <option value="one">1</option>
       <option value="del">Delete</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="Action">
</div>
```

I want to know after pressing action submit which radio is clicked to manipulate it with php, please help me how to do that ? Thanks ...

Comment: When you click the radio button, the form, is it a page or just showing a div content?

Comment: I think I guess how to it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new page, you can use `$_GET` or if it is in same page you can use JavaScript itself to push which radio button is clicked. Example as follows.

```
<div id="mod_div">
   <select name="option" id="option">
       <option value="sel">*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*</option>
       <option value="null">0</option>
       <option value="one">1</option>
       <option value="del">Delete</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="Action">
   <input type='hidden' name='cameFrom' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$_POST["choose"] or $_GET["choose"]
```

will give you an access to the clicked radio button. (the usage of _POST or _GET depends on your "action" attribute of your "form" tag.